# undefined reference to 'abc::abc()' with Dwarf Error: Offset appearing

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I declare an obj :

```
#include "abc.h"

class xxx
{
public: 
  xxx();
  ~xxx();
  abc* q;
...
};
```

in the .cpp file i do the following

`this->q=new abc();` <-error on this line with undefined reference to `abc::abc()`

In the console it also appears this error:

> Dwarf Error: Offset (76195) greater than or equal to .debug_str size
>   (1472).

anyone knows what could be wrong? i'm using eclipse, fedora 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined reference to `abc::abc()`

It is an Linking error which tells you that the linker could not find the definition for `abc::abc()`.

Most likely, You only declared but did not define the no argument constructor for class `abc`.
In your `cpp` file you should have:

```
abc::abc()
{

}
```

If you already have it in place then, You should ensure that the source cpp file which has this definition is being properly linked to your project.

Comment: the abc(); is the contructor in abc class

Comment: @user1282549: Yes. You just declared it in the class definition but did not define it in the cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

> `this->q=new abc();` <-error on this line with undefined reference to
>   abc::abc()

From your error it seems that you have only the declaration of `abc::abc()` and there is **no definition present**. Define `abc::abc()` in source file or make it `inline` in header file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the implementation of the abc class is not included in the build. Add the abc.cpp file to the build.